# Last Page Event Executed On Callback

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, events

I have a WebForm with many controls, including a large number of grids. I added some callback functions on these grids to refresh their DataSource and to update some global variables in a public static class **after** each refresh.

Normally I would add some method calls in the `PageLoadComplete` Event Handler, but the callbacks get raised after that. I also tried using the `OnPrerender`, `OnPrerenderComplete` and `OnSaveStateComplete` method overrides, but these don't seem to work with callbacks. (I can't use the `OnUnload` override since I need to use the `Request` object.)

And here is the Actual Question:
Is there any event handler I can use? Or can I create an event and raise it after everything else has finished?

I want it to execute as the last step in every callback/post-back of any kind (but before page unload so i can still use the `Response` and `Request` objects).

The grids are DevExpress's ASPxGridViews.

---

**UPDATE**

After searching for a while, I found out that the `PreRender` event is fired during async Postbacks of asp:UpdatePanels but not during DevExpress's Callbacks (it is normal behavior).

So, what would really help is finding/creating an event which I can use. I'm also thinking of grabbing the data I want from the Request Object during the PageLoad execution and using them later at Unload.

What are the pros and cons of each approach? Is there anything important that I need to know before making a decision, or is there anything I might be overlooking? I'm concerned about going with the second option since I'd have to declare some class variables and I feel like there are already too many of them.

Comment: Actually, i can store the `Request.` - `Response.` Properties variables and use them later on the unload, but i think that this is just a roundabout way of dealing with this problem, which will be of no use to me later,especially if i want to execute some methods instead of only getting variables

Comment: I removed your [tag:c#] tag. I was tempted to remove the [tag:vb.net] tag as well since your question is pretty much language-agnositc, but since your site is coded in VB.NET I left it there to help answerers know which language to use in their examples.

Comment: You will need to explain "*but the callbacks get raised after that*" and "*these don't seem to work with callbacks*" in a lot more detail. I can't make heads or tails of them. The [`PreRender`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.prerender.aspx) event should be the one you are looking for, so I don't understand what the issue is.

Comment: "but the callbacks get raised after that": That means that these event handlers (ex event_handler(ByVal sender As Object,ByVal e As CustomCallbackEventArgs) Handles grid.CustomCallback) get executed after the Page_Load Handler.

"these don't seem to work with callbacks": The PreRender event Handler doesn't get executed during callbacks.

Also, thanks for editing my post

Comment: After searching for a while, i found out that the PreRender event is fired during async Postbacks of asp:UpdatePanels but not during DevExpress's Callbacks (It is normal behavior). So, what would really help is finding/creating an event which i can use. I'm also thinking of grabbing the data i want from the Request Object during the PageLoad execution and using them later at Unload.What do you think is the better approach? If i have to go with the second one, i'll have to declare some class variables which i want to avoid since there are already too many of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the fact that the `PreRender`,`PreRenderComplete` and `SaveStateComplete` method overrides aren't executed during DevExpress's CallBacks, I found an alternative way to use the OnUnload Method.

First on the Page_Load Method, After some checks using the Request Object, and if the conditions are met, a Handler is attached to the Unload Event, and using a Lambda expression arguments are passed to this sub.

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    '//Some Code// 
        If Request.Params("__CALLBACKPARAM").Contains("REFRESH") Then
            AddHandler Me.Unload, Sub() Page_Unload(sender,e,Request)
        End If
    End Sub
```

This way the Page_Unload sub will be executed only when needed, with all the arguments it needs, while successfully avoiding the addition of more global variables.

```
Protected Sub Page_Unload(sender As Object, e as System.EventArgs, req As HttpRequest)
    '//Some Code//
End Sub
```

The only problem is that i cant remove this handler, but it is no big deal, since on every request to the server the objects are recreated.